# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I get a syntax error: unexpected identifier at line 22. I've been over and over this code, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. It's a code to determine the shortest route from one node to another.

```
"use strict"
function findpath(G,si,di){
    //G is an array of nodes (with id, lat, lon)
    var cvi = si;
    var P=[si];
    var C=[0,P];
    var M=[C];
    var O=[];
    var ctr=0;
    var done = false;
    var reached = false;
    var best = undefined;


    while(!done){
        ctr++;
        if( ctr > 100 ){
            alert("Sorry, can't find the destination.");
            return P;
        }

        for (int i=0;i<M.length;++i){
            var last = M[i[1]].length;
            var v = M[i[1[last]]];

            //select a random neighbor...
            if( v.N.length === 0 ){
                alert("Wat?");
                return [];
            }
            else if( v.N.length === 1 ){
                break;
            }
            else if( v === di ){
                break;
            }
            else {
                for (int j=0;j<v.N.length;++j){
                    var temp = M[i];
                    O.push(temp[1].push(v.N[j]));
                    var dist = distance(v.lat,v.lon,v.N[j].lat,v.N[j].lon);
                    var temp2 = O.length-1;
                    O[temp2[0]]+=dist;
                    if (v.N[j]===di){
                        reached = true;
                        if (best === undefined){
                            console.log("ASSIGN");
                            best = O[temp2];
                        }
                        else {
                            if (O[temp2[0]]<best[0]) {
                                best = O[temp2];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        M = O;
        var any = false;
        for (int i=0;i<M.length;++i) {
            if (M[i[0]]<best[0]) {
                any = true;
            }
        }
        if (!any) {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    //return the path
    return best[1];
}

function distance(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
    for (int i=0;i<M.length;++i){
```

shouldn't have `int`. It should be `var`.

```
    for (var i=0;i<M.length;++i){
```

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA oh my goodness, what a fool I feel like. Thank you for your quick response. I shall now cower in shame.

Answer (score 3):

You have `for (int i=0;i<M.length;++i){`.

`int` is an identifier, but not one that is part of JavaScript.

You probably meant `var`.